# equalizer.getNumberOfPresets() return 0 on certains devices

Tags: android, equalizer, preset

I'm trying to implements presets on an android equalizer, to do so I'm using getNumberOfPresets():

```
 mEqualizer = new Equalizer(0, mMediaPlayer.getAudioSessionId());
 mEqualizer.setEnabled(true);

 short presetNumber = mEqualizer.getNumberOfPresets();
```

On my nexus 4 (4.2.2) I'm getting presetNumber=10 but using an other device running android 4.0.4 I get presetNumber=0. With this last value I am not able to use:

```
mEqualizer.usePreset(short);
```

How can I force the equalizer to use presets?

thx

Answer (score 0):

All the audio effects are hardware-dependent and not guaranteed on all devices.

Because of this, you should always check if the device supports the `AudioEffect`.

You can query available effects using `AudioEffect.queryEffects();`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/AudioEffect.html#queryEffects()

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, music players on the market can use presets with all devices so I thought that there was a way to force this use, but maybe there are not using presets but doing a manual band by band setup with mEqualizer.setBandLevel(band, short);

Comment: Sure. I know a few don't use the built in `AudioEffect` classes at all but run their own effects in the native layer, so comparing against them might not always be useful :)